# Java repeat part of a program with if and boolean operators

Tags: java, if-statement, while-loop

Hello I'm fairly new to java and I had troubles in a little test game.
So this is just a part of the code, I want that the user can repeat the part as often as he like with an while operater.

The code is here:

```
else if (a == 6){
        boolean InGame = true;
        while ( InGame );

        System.out.println("Glückspiel: Wer näher an der zufälligen Zahl ist gewinnt! 1-100");
        System.out.println("Spieler Eins");
        double playerOne = scan.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Spieler Zwei");
        double playerTwo = scan.nextDouble();

        double randomValue = Math.random() * 100.0;

        // Math.abs
        double spacingOne = Math.abs(playerOne - randomValue);
        double spacingTwo = Math.abs(playerTwo - randomValue);
        System.out.println("Die Random Zahl war " + randomValue);

        if (spacingOne < spacingTwo) {
            System.out.println("Spieler Eins hat gewonnen!");
        }

        if (spacingOne > spacingTwo) {
            System.out.println("Spieler Zwei hat gewonnen!");
        }

        if (spacingOne == spacingTwo) {
            System.out.println("Unentschieden!");
        }
        System.out.println("Wenn du nochmal spielen willst schreibe 'ja' wenn nicht 'nein'");
        String PlayAgain = scan.nextLine();
        if  (PlayAgain == "nein");
        boolean inGame = false;
```

Well I have never worked alot with booleans due to me being new in java. 
Would nice if you could help me out.

Comment: `boolean InGame = true; while ( InGame );`  - Your while loop will never end, since `InGame` will be `true` forever.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the scope of your `while`.

```
while(condition) {
    //statement(s)
}
```

Currently all you have is an endless loop with your `while` because you haven't fed it any statements and your condition will therefore stay true.

Answer (score 0):

The code looks pretty much OK, but your string comparison is incorrect at the end of `while` loop. Java compares strings with [**equals()**](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_equals.htm) method. Like this:

`String_1.equals(String2)` 
or in your case 
`if (PlayAgain.equals("nein"))`
And also your while loop doesn't have start and end stated w/ curly brackets:

```
while (condition){
   //insides
}
```

And also - Your `IF`s are not correct. Ending with `;` will always run next line. Rather have this:

```
if  (PlayAgain.equals("nein")){
   boolean inGame = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

hey bro and welcometo the amazing java world ;)
Your could try something like this.

```
    boolean ingame= true;
    while ( ingame) {

    System.out.println("Glückspiel: Wer näher an der zufälligen Zahl ist gewinnt! 1-100");
    System.out.println("Spieler Eins");
    double playerOne = scan.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Spieler Zwei");
    double playerTwo = scan.nextDouble();

    double randomValue = Math.random() * 100.0;

    // Math.abs
    double spacingOne = Math.abs(playerOne - randomValue);
    double spacingTwo = Math.abs(playerTwo - randomValue);
    System.out.println("Die Random Zahl war " + randomValue);

    if (spacingOne < spacingTwo) {
        System.out.println("Spieler Eins hat gewonnen!");
    }

    if (spacingOne > spacingTwo) {
        System.out.println("Spieler Zwei hat gewonnen!");
    }

    if (spacingOne == spacingTwo) {
        System.out.println("Unentschieden!");
    }
    System.out.println("Wenn du nochmal spielen willst schreibe 'ja' wenn nicht 'nein'");
    String PlayAgain = scan.nextLine();
    if  (PlayAgain.equals("nein"));
    ingame= false; 
}
```

PS: Immer weiter üben, Deutschland braucht mehr JAVA-Entwickler ;)

Comment: Thanks but now it says that "InGame" is already defined in the scope...

Comment: i didnt see that mistake, u defined the boolean ingame on top of ur code. delete the "boolean" word on bottom that u just change the value and dont define it again.

Answer (score 0):

```
else if (a == 6){
Scanner scan=new Scanner(System.in);
            boolean InGame = true;
            do{

            System.out.println("Glückspiel: Wer näher an der zufälligen Zahl ist gewinnt! 1-100");
            System.out.println("Spieler Eins");
            double playerOne = scan.nextDouble();
            System.out.println("Spieler Zwei");
            double playerTwo = scan.nextDouble();

            double randomValue = Math.random() * 100.0;

            // Math.abs
            double spacingOne = Math.abs(playerOne - randomValue);
            double spacingTwo = Math.abs(playerTwo - randomValue);
            System.out.println("Die Random Zahl war " + randomValue);

            if (spacingOne < spacingTwo) {
                System.out.println("Spieler Eins hat gewonnen!");
            }

            if (spacingOne > spacingTwo) {
                System.out.println("Spieler Zwei hat gewonnen!");
            }

            if (spacingOne == spacingTwo) {
                System.out.println("Unentschieden!");
            }
            System.out.println("Wenn du nochmal spielen willst schreibe 'ja' wenn nicht 'nein'");
            String PlayAgain = scan.nextLine();
            if  (PlayAgain == "nein"){
            boolean inGame = false;
            }
            }
            while ( InGame );
```

Answer (score 0):

i have just modified your code and it's working perfectly

```
boolean InGame = true;
        while ( InGame ) { // begin of while loop

            System.out.println("Glückspiel: Wer näher an der zufälligen Zahl ist gewinnt! 1-100");
            System.out.println("Spieler Eins");
            double playerOne = scan.nextDouble();
            System.out.println("Spieler Zwei");
            double playerTwo = scan.nextDouble();

            double randomValue = Math.random() * 100.0;

            // Math.abs
            double spacingOne = Math.abs(playerOne - randomValue);
            double spacingTwo = Math.abs(playerTwo - randomValue);
            System.out.println("Die Random Zahl war " + randomValue);

            if(spacingOne < spacingTwo) {
                System.out.println("Spieler Eins hat gewonnen!");
            }

            else if(spacingOne > spacingTwo) { // use else if condition
                System.out.println("Spieler Zwei hat gewonnen!");
            }

            else {
                System.out.println("Unentschieden!");
            }

            System.out.println("Wenn du nochmal spielen willst schreibe 'ja' wenn nicht 'nein'");
            String PlayAgain = scan.next();
            if (PlayAgain.equals("nein")) { // use equal() method
                InGame = false;
            }

        } // end of while loop
```